# How do I import Active directory ldif file to openldap server?

Tags: active-directory, schema, openldap, ldif

I am having a ldif file which exported from Active directory. it contains users and group details. I have tried to import directly through jxloper, it throws error. How do I import Active directory ldif file to openldap server?

Comment: What did you try so far? What is the error ? Pleas provide more and specific information

Comment: 'It throws error' is not a problem description.

Comment: Without seeing examples of entries one cannot give more help. Furthermore you should mention what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The LDAP schema of MS Active Directory is very specific and completely different to that installed in OpenLDAP default installations. It's nearly impossible to get AD exports directly imported into OpenLDAP without heavy sanitizing and/or schema tweaking.

Just some examples:

- The users in AD have object class `User` which does not exist in OpenLDAP
- The groups in AD have object class `Group` which does not exist in OpenLDAP

If you want to mimic behaviour of MS AD your best option would be to try **Samba4** by following this docs:

[Setting up Samba as an Active Directory Domain Controller](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_an_Active_Directory_Domain_Controller)